# handling clicks on an element in php for loop in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have been trying to use jquery click event with an element in php for loop. How can I transfer the counter value to jquery before click.

My PHP Code:

```
<?php $counter=0;foreach($a as $abc){$counter++;?>
        <div id="mail_<?php echo $counter;?>" class="ma" />
   <?php }?>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ma").click
```

How could I use this counter variable before click in jquery.

Comment: Before Click means? Onload itself?

Comment: How could I get that counter variable value anyhow??

Comment: parseInt(element.getAttribute('id')) ? Why do you even need this anyway ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example : Full HTML Code. Just copy, Paste & Run in Browser.  [Used @RafH's Solution]

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>jQuery Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    div { color:blue; margin:3px; cursor:pointer; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".ma").click(function() {
      var counter = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
      alert("Counter ID "+counter);
    });
    }); 

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
        for($counter=1;$counter<=10;$counter++)
        {
        ?>
        <div id="mail_<?php echo $counter;?>" class="ma" />Test</div>
       <?php 
       }
       ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why "before" click ? In the following example, you get the counter value of the clicked element.

```
$(".ma").on('click', function(e) {
  var counter = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
});
```

Note that you can do the same thing without using id as your counter starts at 0 and just increment one by one.

```
  $(".ma").on('click', function(e) {
     var counter = $(this).index();
    });
```

If you need the final value of counter, you can use `$(".ma").length`

Comment: how could jquery will identify which element was clicked??

Comment: $(".ma") means all element with class "ma". Inside the click event handler of this selector, $(this) refers to the currently clicked ".ma" element. http://api.jquery.com/click/